# Validate, filter and convert string to date using Isdate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am having a problem converting string to date using a isdate for validation and here's my script

```
USE SomeDB
    SELECT  InstallDate
    FROM         tblInstalls
    WHERE     (ISDATE(InstallDate) = 0) AND (InstallDate IS NOT NULL)
```

--Result---
27/05/2002
27/08/2004
19/06/2002
26/06/2002
17/05/2002
15/09/2002
15/04/2004
19/04/2004
22/04/2004
22/04/2004
22/06/904

**And now I would like to convert which can be converted to 103 format and ignore the data which cannot be converted...**

```
USE SomeDB
SELECT  top 100   convert(DATETIME, InstallDate,  103))
FROM         tblInstalls
WHERE     (ISDATE(InstallDate) = 0) AND (InstallDate IS NOT NULL)
```

---Result--
2002-05-27 00:00:00.000
2004-08-27 00:00:00.000
2002-06-19 00:00:00.000
2002-06-26 00:00:00.000
2002-05-17 00:00:00.000
2002-09-15 00:00:00.000
2004-04-15 00:00:00.000
2004-04-19 00:00:00.000
2004-04-22 00:00:00.000
2004-04-22 00:00:00.000
22/06/904 <-The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

My objective is to clean a data in the right date format and remove the unnecessary data which cannot be converted. Hoping and appreciated you help in advance..

Comment: Cast the string InstallDate to a date first, then convert the result to a string.  Plus, don't you want the records where isdate(installdate) = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't determine which order the engine will process. It may do the conversion of the row before or after it has filtered them.

As a side note, you have top but no order by. That will return whatever rows the sql engine wants to and it won't always be consistent. Secondly the additional where predicate of InstallDate IS NOT NULL is just wasted effort because you are already filtering only rows that have ISDATE = 1 and NULL is not a valid date.

```
with ValidDates as
(
    select top 100 InstallDate
    from tblInstalls
    where ISDATE(InstallDate) = 1
    --need an order by here
)

select convert(DATETIME, InstallDate,  103)
from ValidDates
```

Comment: Actually, the OP filters where isDate = 0. naturally, invalid dates will pass this filter while valid dates will not. the reason they pass this filter is the default dateformat is probably mdy and not dmy on the OP's server.

Comment: @Sean Lange Hi I am still receiving -> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Edited the IsDate check. Thanks @ZoharPeled. Doh!!

Answer (score 3):

First, `IsDate` returns `0` if the string value it gets is **not** a valid date.
you need to filter by `IsDate(InstallDate) = 1`.
Second, you probably get `0` as the result of `IsDate` since the default date format of your server is not `dmy`.

Here is something that will work:

```
set dateformat dmy; -- NOTE THIS ROW!

select convert(datetime, InstallDate,  103)
from tblInstalls
where isdate(InstallDate) = 1 -- NOTE: IsDate returns 1 for valid dates
```

[see sql fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/004d5/1)

btw, sean had some really good points in his answer, he only got the reason for the error wrong. AFAIK, the select clause will always be performed after the where clause.

Comment: Yes Zohar. My brain was confusing myself and was thinking of multiple where predicates.